# How do I shrink a flexbox with two elements inside of it, using Tailwind CSS?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I have been trying to shrink my flex box, but I haven't had much luck getting this to work.

Here is the code sample:

```
    <div className="flex justify-center bg-white rounded w-23 mx-auto">
         <p>Contact Number</p>
         <button className="px-4 py-3"><DropIcon /></button>
    </div>
```

[This is the current state of the element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54Qz9.png)

Comment: why do you want to shrink these elements?. post full requirements.

Comment: Put another div inside the one with flex display and set margins/padding on that?

Comment: I have checked the docs for 2.x and 3.x. The width `w-23` doesnt even exist. You could rather use `w-24`, this does exist

Comment: Depending on what you mean by "shrinking it", you might consider using `inline-flex`, instead of `flex` and a set width. This will reduce the flex to the width of your content.